# how to merge eo, vo, am, and projects in oracle adf (JDev 12.2.1 JSF 2.2)

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have an ADF application where EO, VO, and AM are kept in separate applications exported as ADF Library and then eventually imported to the ViewController project.

For some reason the plan has changed and I need to merge previous developments into one single application holding everything (ie. EO, VO, AM, and VC). Previously I posted a discussion on "JDeveloper & ADF" community [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4009885) and it turned out the quickest way is to merge the src folders, *.jpx, and the bc4j.xcfg files where the tricky part is the latest (ie. bc4j.xcfg).

I have pretty much done everything except for the bc4j.xcfg.

When I try to run the application module, it throws the below error

```
XML File not found for the Container /com/asrandisheh/mis/asset/model/AssetsModel.jpx: MDS-00013: no metadata found for metadata object "/com/asrandisheh/mis/asset/model/AssetsModel.jpx" 
MDS-00201: PDocument not found in MetadataStore : [store-type=DefaultMetadataStore lookup-order=Classpath]
```

And the BC4J.xcfg is like below:

[image]

I know that jbo.project attribute hasn't been set correctly. So, I have the below questions.

1) I believe that jbo.project is supposed to point to path for the project holding the application module. Is it a right assumption?

2) How is this value should be set. What is the type of value? Is it filename path or package path. I believe it is package path. If the later applies, then where is the path for the holding JPR file stored cuz I checked the JPR file but couldn't find any relevant value showing the package path for the holding project.

Please let me know if you have any clue.

Regards,
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered your question here https://community.oracle.com/message/14206669#14206669

Timo